# Differential equation (2nd order) with divergent coefficients.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this equation:

$$x(x-1)y''+6x^2y'+3y=0$$

I try to get the series for the solution around $x=0$, using Frobenius (however it's written). the first solution must be of the form:

$$y_1=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^{n+1}$$

If I try to get coefficients, I will get a divergent series of coefficients, in which I can't see any sense. The first one is $c_1=\frac{3}{2}c_0$, I calculated the first 1000 by computer and the never go down, although I think you can deduce that from the expression for the coefficients:
$$a_{n+2}=\frac{[(n+2)(n+1)+3]a_{n+1}+6(n+1)a_{n}}{(n+3)(n+2)}$$
Since the upper thing goes "like" a factorial with the $a_{n-1,2}$.

So... how would you get the solutions by series for this? What does it mean that the coefficients are divergent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without looking at the actual form of your specific coefficients, the fact that the coefficients of a power series go to infinity is not a "curse" — it is possible, albeit it implies that the radius of convergence will be at most $1$ (if it is $0$, *then* it is a problem).

For instance, consider $a_n = n$: the radius of convergence is $R=1$, as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n$ is well-defined for all $|x|<1$ (a characterization is actually $R=\sup \{r \geq 0: a_n r^n \to 0\}$).

Even more striking, $a_n = 2^n$: the radius of convergence is $R=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Yes... Is there a relatively simple way to get the radius of convergence without knowing the general expression $a_n(n)$, from that recurrence relation?

Comment: BTW, if fröbenius theorem warranties the existence of the solution, doesn't it mean the radius of convergence is bigger that 0?

Comment: I'm ashamed to say that I don't know this theorem... I cannot help in that regard, I tend to do it "manually".
On a different level, I do not find the same recurrence relation as you do -- I might be wrong, though; what I get is 
$a_0=0$, $a_2=\frac{3}{2} a_1$ and, for $n\geq 3$,
$$
a_n = \frac{(n^2-3n+5)a_{n-1}+6(n-2)a_{n-2}}{n(n-1)}
$$

Comment: I'm sorry, the coefficients $a_k$ were wrong, I've corrected them, although I still get something different than you... still the same i had before. Anyway I already got my answer, so I have accepted yours. Thanks.

Comment: By the way (it is not a proof, but a hunch backed by substituting in the recurrence relation), I have the hazy feeling that $a_n\operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} n$. If you can prove it (provided it is correct), then you get the radius of convergence.

Comment: Does this work?: $(n+3)(n+2)>(n+2)(n+1)+3$ by developing the parenthesis it is: $5n>3n-1$, which is obvious, so the recurrence relation is: 
$$a_{n+2}<\frac{[(n+2)(n+3)]a_{n+1}+6(n+2)a_{n}}{(n+3)(n+2)}=a_{n-1}+6\frac{a_{n-2}}{n+3}$$, so it's bounded by something that doesn't diverge?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm wrong, that bound diverges as well.